# How to start/stop inactivity timer in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to start an inactivity timer for 5 seconds or X seconds WHILST a function executes?

Here is what I'm doing:

I'm creating a screenshot:

```
     //todo: I need an activity timer [start] here

                   screenshotController.capture(
                    //delay: Duration(seconds: 5),
                      pixelRatio: 2,
                      path: newPath
                  ).then((io.File image) {
                    //Capture Done
                    _imageFile = image;

                  }).catchError((onError) {
                    print(onError);
                  });

   // todo: I need an activity timer [stop] here.
```

The user cannot interrupt the creation of the PNG file. I need some kind of progress timer to start/stop. I do not wish to use Progress_HUD. This is very ugly. I've tried it. I have to change my entire code to accommodate how this app works.

I'm inclined to use CircularProgress..().. but how can I make it start? and how can I make it stop??

How can I know when the screenshotController is still active?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a lot about screenshot plugin but if you just want to run a function every x seconds you can use Timer

In initState()

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {

      //Write here your function and logic

    });
  }
```

if your function is async put the timer in didChangeDependencies(),
you can stop the timer by writing some logic